# Java fxml, populate the item on the list on a GUI

Tags: java, user-interface, fxml

I'm making a music player application, using java and Scenebuilder to create GUI.
Once music files are imported, they are displayed in the list.
When I search the music, this program can return if the music is on the list or not, and set the music as the next music played.
[enter image description here][1]

Here is the question. How do I populate (highlight) the row that has the searched music?

```
@FXML
private ListView<String> listBox;
private ObservableList<String> list = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

@FXML
private void searchMusic(ActionEvent event) {
    avl.Find(searchTextBox.getText());

    if (avl.Find(searchTextBox.getText()).equals("found!")) {
        labelFind.setText("Found!");
        listBox.focusModelProperty();
        int searchInd = listBox.getItems().indexOf(searchTextBox.getText());
        listBox.getFocusModel().focus(searchInd);
        currentSong.setText(listBox.getFocusModel().getFocusedItem());
    } else {
        labelFind.setText("There is no such song.");
    }
```

I'm using the AVL tree for this project. Even if I focus the row, it doesn't populate the row.
Your answer will be appreciated.
Thank you.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/76NnV.png

Answer (score 0):

How about using the most popular way and populating the `List` only with your searched element?

I do not know what your `avl.find()` function does, but the logic would be simple.

1. When the search button is clicked, the element with this name will be searched in the `List` and will be extracted.
2. Clear your `ListView<String> listBox`, `listBox.getItems().clear()`, and then add your found item here. And then the user will see only the searched element.
3. If not found, just clear your list and show an empty list, indicating that there is no such object.

Highlighting is possible, do not get me wrong, just more complicated than the solution above.